# Check if some decimal values are equal

Tags: c#

I am using the following line of code to check if the decimals are equal or not but its showing syntax error.

```
if (ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1 == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2 == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_3)
```

Whats the correct method ?

Comment: With some bracketing, it would be legal, but not express your intent (if I understand your intent correctly). If you'd done `((Sys==1)==(2==3))` it would compile but wouldn't ensure that all four variables are equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1 
 && ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1 == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2 
 && ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2 == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant just do `A == B == C == D`. You have to use the `&&` (AND) operator, like so:

```
if (a == b && b == c && c == d && d == e)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Which means `if a equals b AND b equals c AND c equals d AND d equals e then`.

Why does this happen? Because the [equality operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) takes two arguments of the same type. `a == b` results in a boolean (`true` or `false`) and you compare this result to the next value of `c` which is still of type `decimal` and you cant compare a `boolean` to a `decimal` as they are not of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator is a binary operator and is evaluated from left to right. This means, it evaluates first

```
ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1
```

which gives a boolean value and then this boolean value is compared to

```
(true or false) == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2
```

which again gives a boolean value and then this second boolean value is compared to

```
(true or false) == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_3
```

You get an error, because you compare values of incompatible types.

The correct way to compare multiple values is to combine them by the logical `&&` (and) operator, for example

```
if (ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1 
    && ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2 
    && ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System == ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if (ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System.Equals(ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1).Equals(ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2.Equals(ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Comparison operator return boolean value, i.e. True or False. So first comparison returns boolean value and that you are comparing with decimal. Hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write method like this:

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(params T[] values)
    where T : struct
{
    if (values.Length < 2) 
        return true;

    T first = values[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!values[i].Equals(first))
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

And use it to compare all values:

```
if (AllEqual(ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_System,
             ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_1,
             ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_2,
             ProgramVariables.MSR_AR_EB_3))
```